# How to give an identifier for UIViewController (Swift) which has no storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have multiple view controllers created programmatically. (No storyboards)

Is there a way of giving an identifier or something to differentiate between view controllers just like giving an identifier for storyboards.

Comment: Is checking the type not enough?

Comment: are they have one class? you can check it, also you can use self.restorationIdentifier

Comment: I ended up giving each viewController restoraionIdentifier name like this (viewController.restorationIdentifier = viewControllerIdentifier) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

NO, there are no ways to give an identifier to differentiate between view controllers. The name of your UIViewController is its identifier.